# CSS input:not(input:focus) selector?

Tags: css

Is it possible to select an input that does not have focus?

```css
div{
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  padding:10px;
}
intput:not(:focus) {
    background: inherit !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using the word `intput`? I edited it thinking it was a typo.

Comment: yep, that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax is `input:not(:focus)`. That will select all inputs that aren’t in focus.

Comment: I've updated question with an example. not working...

Comment: @boruchsiper `input` instead of `intput`

Comment: @boruchsiper Yeah, there’s a typo in your selector.